# white blood cells and cancer cells transport through lymphatic vessels

Tags: cancer, biophysics, literature, computational-model, lymphatic-system

It is a well-known fact that both of these cells can reach the lymphatic vessels from interstitial space. How does it do so physically? Are there any mathematical models describing this process? It seems like there are endothelial cells along the lymphatic vessels that act like valves, so I would assume that these "valves" open, the cancer cells/WBCs would fit through to reach the lumen?

This question is also a reference request. I am looking for papers that describes the process of intravasation of WBCs and cancer cells into the lymphatic capillaries? Mathematical models are preferable but this is such a niche topic that probably there are no mathematical models.

Comment: good question +1 specially on the cancer cell part.looking forward to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "valves" are basically one way valves that just prevent backflow of interstitial fluid from the lymph into the interstitial space, so they do not specifically affect the flux of WBCs, cancer cells, etc. into the lymph vessels. In terms of a mathematical model of flux into the lymph vessels, you could use Poiseuille's law to determine the flow rate of interstitial fluid through the "valves", then multiply by the concentration of WBCs, etc. in the interstitial fluid to get the flux of the given cells into the lymph vessels. Of course, that is just one possible model for one parameter (cell flux).

Comment: I am looking for more of a biomechanical/fluid dynamics model. Also, you haven't explained how the WBCs/ cancer cells go through the valves...